# Bad file descriptor in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, file

I am downloading a file with boto3 from AWS S3, it's a basic JSON file.

```
{
    "Counter": 0,
    "NumOfReset": 0,
    "Highest": 0
}
```

I can open the JSON file, but when I go to dump it back to the same file after changing some values, I get `IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`.

```
with open("/tmp/data.json", "rw") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
    i = data["Counter"]
    i = i + 1
    if i >= data["Highest"]:
        data["Highest"] = i
    json.dump(data, fh)
    fh.close()
```

Am I just using the wrong file mode or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: open the file for reading, read in your information, make your change, then open the file for writing, and dump it.

Comment: `rw` doesn't exist. You're looking for `r+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things. Its `r+` not `rw`, and if you want to overwrite the previous data, you need to return to the beginning of the file, using `fh.seek(0)`. Otherwise, the changed JSON string would be appended.

```
with open("/tmp/data.json", "r+") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
    i = data["Counter"]
    i = i + 1
    if i >= data["Highest"]:
        data["Highest"] = i

    fh.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, fh)
    fh.close()
```

But that may overwrite the data only partially. So closing and re-opening the file with `w` is probably a better idea.

```
with open("/tmp/data.json", "r") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

i = data["Counter"]
i = i + 1
if i >= data["Highest"]:
    data["Highest"] = i

with open("/tmp/data.json", "w") as fh:
    json.dump(data, fh)
    fh.close()
```

No need to `fh.close()`, that's what `with .. as` is for.